# Common Ground to Earth?

Tags: ground

I am looking into building this stereo amplifier based on this circuit: [2 x 22 Amplifier](http://www.circuitstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/02/2x22-w-amp.jpg)

However, as I am pretty new to circuit building, I have a question about the ground lines: Do i tie all of the ground lines to the earth ground on the power supply? On the schematic, it shows +12v in, and out to "GND", and i am not sure if I should use the common ground line by itself as the end point, or if i should ground the common to earth. Any help would be great, and apologies if this is somewhat redundant, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ground points should all be connected together, and to the negative terminal of the power supply.  There is no need to connect them to "Earth Ground".

Comment: Great, thank you. As a followup: in this case then, would a floating negative terminal be necessary for the circuit to function, or would it not make a difference?